# Laravel: Single Listener for many Events

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to have one universal listener which would send an email?

The current structure as I see it, ties only one listener to a single event. And the `handle` method of an event expects an instance of a particular event always.

Is it possible to have that universal listener and how would you implement it?

Comment: You can fire multiple events inside a main event.

Comment: Ah, the problem is in listeners.. I want one listener for different events.//..

Comment: Yeah! but 1 listener will be tied to an event, then when that event is called..try to call other events, you can even use Request::segment to see which url was responsible for the event call, and call other related events

Comment: well, that is not clean at all...

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer would be "Event Subscribers". An example can be found here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#event-subscribers

Sadly, everyone skipped that part in any "Laravel Events" tutorials I came across.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the game here, but I was looking for an answer to the same question, so thought i'd share my solution.

The solution that worked for me, was `Wildcard Event Listeners` (see https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events#registering-events-and-listeners)

I had initially set up an abstract 'base' event for the category of events I wanted to listen to with a single listener, and because there are so many of them i put them in a subdirectory of app/events (app/events/ModelHooks).

It turns out you can't listen to an abstract class or interface of events, but fortunately because i had them in a sub-namespace i was able to add my listener for all of them by adding this to my EventServiceProvider:

```
$listen = [
    'App\Events\ModelHooks\*' => [
        ModelHookListener::class
    ]
];
```